# How to keep the stack multithread in it memory space

Tags: multithreading

I want to know about what is the best way to develop a thread pool in java to
 do multitask and ,how to stack memory keep it when this sample program executing .
 please explain me about what is the best way to implement thread pool?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class A implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("A  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

}

class B implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("B "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

}

class C implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("C  "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

}

public class threadrunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService bn = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Runnable t1 = new A();
        Runnable t2 = new B();
        Runnable t3 = new C();
        bn.execute(t1);
          bn.execute(t2);
            bn.execute(t3);

       bn.shutdwon();
    }

}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)` "implements a thread pool". What do you mean by "keep the stack"?

Comment: what is the stack behavior when executing thread

Comment: Every thread gets its own stack. Every runnable gets assigned a thread (not necessarily a different one from the other runnables).